# Calculate position with position depending force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

I have an equation that says $$a(t)= \alpha * s(t)+\beta$$ where $a$ is the acceleration, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants, $s$ is position and $t$ the time. My question is how to get the resulting position function $p(t)$ that gives the position in dependence to the time.

I fail to understand how to get this equation since the acceleration depends on the position and vice versa this seems like a circular reference to me.

Comment: Have you taken a course on differential equations?  What you have here is: $$\frac{d^2s}{dt^2} = \alpha s + \beta$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a circular reference, it's an [ordinary differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation):
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=f(y)
$$
In particular, it is a *general 2nd order ODE*, which, for some functions $f(y)$, has known analytic solutions.

One way to think of this is a mass on a spring:

[image: spring]
(source: [Julius O Smith, Standorf *MUS420/EE367A Supplementary:
The Laplace Transform*](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/Laplace/Mass_Spring_Oscillator_Time_Domain_Solution.html))

If you watch the motion of the spring, then you'll note that at each point in time $t$, the direction of the motion depends on where it was just beforehand. So the velocity, $\dot{x}=dx/dt$, is pointing to the right in the image, but after compressing all the way, the velocity would go to the left. The rate of change of the velocity (acceleration, $a=dv/dt$) also depends on where it was.

This is what [Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke's_law) says: the force, $F(t)$, depends on the position, $x(t)$:
$$
F(t)=-kx(t)
$$
but we also know that $F=m\,(d^2x/dt^2)$, so
$$
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{k}{m}x(t)
$$
which is similar to your equation.

There are numerous methods of solving these types of equations (e.g., [trial functions](http://www.efunda.com/math/ode/linearode_undeterminedcoeff.cfm) or  [integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral)), but it takes practice & experience to know when to use which.